# Count values in a row with ANZAHL2(D:D)

Tags: excel, count

I am counting the values of the row D with `ANZAHL2(D:D)`.
It is working but I want to count the values `-1`.
So I have to modify it to `ANZAHL2(D:D) -1` but it not working

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve? please explain better your question

Comment: If you are just trying to count the number of times -1 is used, use `Countif` function (`ZÄHLENWENN` in German). `=ZÄHLENWENN(D:D,-1)`